# Registration process by OAuth2

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization

I have been analyzing security process in 3gpp specs and the registration process in the spec. explained with that flow. The flow represents the registration of a client to the server.[image: From SPEC].  [image: spec 2]

I am not a security specialist and i do not understand why we send Oauth2 token in step 1. Doesn't the access token send after the registration? I know that the access token used for authorization if the client known. I know that is a weird topic and I tried to explain it briefly i hope you understand if you dont you can always ask me.

Comment: This is not a code related question, it's more a technical debate and will generate opinion based answers. Please state the sources to support your assumptions.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that  [link](https://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/2020-03/Rel-16/33_series/33122-g20.zip) page:11 @Pimenta